# All cells not running after restart and run all inn jupyter

Tags: jupyter

When I ran an infinite loop accidentally, restart and run all cells command did not execute all cells. Some cells did not show the output and also the cell numbering was altered. What should I do.

I tried running all cells again but some cells did not show any output.
Cells from in between the notebook were running and altered the numbering.

Comment: Your question isn't posed in a way that anyone can offer you much help. Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future attempts. It sounds like may be encountering a hidden state issue now. Perhaps you ran some code and then deleted the cell with it? Now when you try to run things, you aren't reproducing the state of the namespace you had before. A good tip when using Jupyter, is to do `Restart Kernel and Run all` often and regularly. You'll pick up on such issues much sooner and may be able to better recall what you did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.